# observable hq. what is wrongs

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I am getting unexpected string warning. can someone help. The same program runs of the console perfectly fine.

```js
class MyArray {
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.data = {};
  }
  get(index) {
    return this.data[index];
  }
  push(item) {
    this.data[this.length] = item;
    this.length++;
    console.log(this.length);
  }
  pop() {
    const lastItem = this.data[this.length - 1];
    delete this.data[this.length - 1];
    this.length--;
    return lastItem;
  }
}

const newArr = new MyArray();
newArr.push('h1');
newArr.push('you');
```

I am getting error at `const newArr = new MyArray()` as "SyntaxError: Unexpected token". Why is this happening?

Comment: It is very difficult to help with the details you provided. Please add more info or code to generate that error.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Is this all of the code? Are you running this with node? Please clarify, and include more details, including all of the code you're running and the full stack trace, at the very least.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal are you running it on observablehq.com ? if so you should start on https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript

Answer (score 0):

ObservableHQ is not Javascript. Please take a look at this document: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript

You are missing enclosing your whole code into `{}`.